# How is it obvious that that (foldr Cons Nil) just copies a list?

Tags: functional-programming, haskell

I am currently reading [Why Functional Programming Matters](https://www.cs.kent.ac.uk/people/staff/dat/miranda/whyfp90.pdf) by John Hughes.

In the "Gluing Functions Together" section, after having explained that `(foldr f a)` is a function that replaces all occurrences of `Cons` in a list by `f`, and all occurrences of `Nil` by `a` (which I understand), the author writes: "Now it’s obvious that `(foldr Cons Nil)` just copies a list" and gives this example to illustrate the point:

```
append [1, 2] [3, 4] = foldr Cons [3, 4] [1, 2]
                     = foldr Cons [3, 4] (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil))
                     = Cons 1 (Cons 2 [3, 4]))
                     = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I do not understand why on the third line of the given example, `(Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil))` is suddenly at the front and consequently why the list does not end up being `[3, 4, 1, 2]`. Is the `Nil` in `(Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil))` `a` and is `Cons [3, 4]` `f` if `foldr`'s definition is `foldr f a`?

In which way is it obvious that `foldr Cons Nil` just copies a list?

Comment: If `(foldr f a)` means "replace all `Cons` with `f` and all `Nil` with `a`, then replacing all `Cons` with `Cons` and replacing all `Nil` with `Nil` should leave the list looking the same as it started, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've got to substitute 3 times to get from line 2 to line 3.
Using the definition of `foldr` given on page 5:

```
(foldr f x) Nil = x
(foldr f x) (Cons a l) = f a ((foldr f x) l)
```

taking the second line of the given example,
and substituting using the 2nd line of the `foldr` defn, I'll write the variable matching under each argument:

```
                 = foldr Cons [3, 4] (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil))
defn:             (foldr  f     x)   (Cons a      l   )     = f a ((foldr f x) l)

gives:             Cons 1 ((foldr Cons [3,4]) (Cons 2 Nil) )
```

substituting again for this  ..........^ occurrence of foldr gives:

```
                   Cons 1 (Cons 2 ((foldr Cons [3,4] Nil)
```

and again, but this time taking the 1st line of the `foldr` defn:

```
                   Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons [3,4])
```

Answer (score 4):

Replacing `Cons` by `Cons` and `Nil` by `Nil` keeps things the same!

In the given `append` example, `[3, 4]` is what replaces `Nil`.